# Android - Set SearchView MenuItem width on expansion and iconified

Tags: android, searchview

I have menu which contains 4 items with different width from the default width of Android's menu item.. Here's the code of the `SearchView` in `res/menu`

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_toolbar_top_searchBtn"
    android:orderInCategory="3"
    android:title="@string/search"
    android:icon="@drawable/menu_search"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/menu_layout_search"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

My `menu_layout_search` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/menuitem_width"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/actionBarItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:searchIcon="@drawable/menu_search"/>
```

As the width is set to menuitem_width which is the same as the other menus' width, when it is pressed, it stays on that width.

I've tried using :

```
    final Point p = new Point();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(p);

    final LayoutParams matchParentParams = new LayoutParams(p.x, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    final LayoutParams wrapContentParams = new LayoutParams(p.x, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            toolbarImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            toolbarTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            notificationMenu.setVisible(false);
            drawerMenu.setVisible(false);
            searchView.setLayoutParams(matchParentParams);
            searchView.requestFocus();
        }
    });

    searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClose() {
            toolbarImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            toolbarTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            notificationMenu.setVisible(true);
            drawerMenu.setVisible(true);
            searchView.setLayoutParams(wrapContentParams);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

To set its params back and forth between `MATCH_PARENT` and `WRAP_CONTENT` but when it goes back to iconified, it ruins the whole menu layout by having all menu moved to the left (they were on the right).

What am I doing wrong here? Is there actually a simpler way to set width on `iconified` and `not iconified` version of `SearchView`?